# How to map array of object in typescript/react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My main problem is that the value "name" is correctly showing in dev console, whereas I cannot see this value on view.

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: "red", color: "white"}}>
{resultsDataFetching?.map(({name}:any, index: number) => {console.log("nameFrom", name)
    return(
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <p>{name}</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    )})}
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine see https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-napier-jxj0wh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You must have problem somewhere else

Comment: I had, the results was cover by another div and I did not notice that at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You have return   the whole div. right now you only return what is inside the map.

Note that each component can return only one element at the end... one Big div , one big forum

```
 return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>
            {Arr?.map(({ name }: any, index: number) => {
                console.log("nameFrom", name)
                return (

                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <p>{name}</p>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
```